# Angular 1.5 Component Unit Testing with Karma Jasmine Failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test an Angular Component with Karma Jasmine for the very first time.

My `index.html` looks like :

```
<body ng-app="heroApp">
  <!-- components match only elements -->
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <b>Hero</b><br>
  <hero-detail hero="ctrl.hero"></hero-detail>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And `index.js` looks like :

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
    angular.module('heroApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
        this.hero = {
            name: 'Miles Bronson'
        };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

And the **component** `heroDetail.js` looks like :

```
(function(angular){
    'use strict';

    function HeroDetailController(){

    }

    angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail',{
        template:'<span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>',
        controller:HeroDetailController,
        bindings:{
            hero: '='
        }
    });

})(window.angular);
```

Now my karma spec file looks like :

```
describe('Component:heroDetailComponent',function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('heroApp');
    });

    var element,
        scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.outside = "Miles Bronson";
        element = angular.element('<hero-detail hero="{{outside}}"></hero-detail>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$apply();
    }));

    it('should render the text',function(){
        var span = angular.find('span');
        expect(span.text()).toBe('Name: Miles Bronson')
    });

});
```

But this **failed**. `Saying :`

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) Component:heroDetailComponent should render the text FAILED
        Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{outside}}] starting at [{outside}}].
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Boutside%7D%7D&p4=%7Boutside%7D%7D
            at bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
            at AST.throwError (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14893:11)
            at AST.object (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14882:16)
            at AST.primary (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14771:22)
            at AST.unary (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14759:19)
            at AST.multiplicative (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14746:21)
            at AST.additive (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14737:21)
            at AST.relational (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14728:21)
            at AST.equality (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14719:21)
            at AST.logicalAND (bower_components/angular/angular.js:14711:21)
        Error: Declaration Location
            at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3118:25)
            at Suite.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:30:16)
            at test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:23:1
        TypeError: angular.find is not a function
            at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:39:28)
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (2 FAILED) (0.641 secs / 0.089 secs)
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**  Please help.

Also , I am declaring an `outside` variable here and testing the same.

**How can I take the variable from the controller and test it without locally declaring it ?**

Comment: It's supposed to be `outside`, not `{{outside}}`. I don't understand your second question. `outside` has to come from somewhere.